# Parse Object Not Saving in Dashboard

Tags: java, android, parse-platform

When I try to save a ParseObject in my Android app it does not seem to be saving to the Dashboard.  There seems to be no error's showing.  Here's my code.

*N.B: The code is nested within `protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)`*

```
continue_reg.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(View arg0) {
            firstNameTxt = first_name.getText().toString();
            lastNameTxt = last_name.getText().toString();

            if (firstNameTxt.equals("") && lastNameTxt.equals("")) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Please complete all fields", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

            } else {

                ParseObject patientInfo = new ParseObject("PatientInformation");
                patientInfo.put("firstName", firstNameTxt);
                patientInfo.put("lastName", lastNameTxt);
                patientInfo.saveInBackground();

                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Complete", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to use the SaveCallback(), so you can see if any error appears.

```
patientInfo.saveInBackground(new SaveCallback() {
                                @Override
                                public void done(ParseException e) {
                                    if (e == null) {                                          
                                        // No error, the object was saved
                                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Complete", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                                    } else {
                                        // Error saving object, print the logs
                                        e.printStackTrace();
                                    }
                                }
                            });
```

Comment: In your code you will always see the toast. Because saving is done not on the main thread and you don't know if object was saved or not. In my code above the toast is shown if the object was saved in database. If the object was not saved it will print the logs, so you can see where the error appears.

Comment: I've got it solve, I had the following in a separate onClick:   

`Intent i = new Intent(UserReg1.this, UserReg2.class);`
`startActivity(i);`

Comment: @seamus911 Log.e("TAG", "Error Msg :-  " + e.getMessage());